# Is it possible to walk from Dubai Terminal 1 arrivals to Dubai Terminal 1 departures?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, dubai, lufthansa, indigo

I will be arriving in Dubai Terminal 1 with Lufthansa. I need to go catch an Indigo flight from Dubai Terminal 1 departures. Is it possible to walk from Dubai Terminal 1 arrivals to departures?

Comment: DXB airport, I assume?

Comment: Arrivals is on Level 2, Departures on Level 1 https://www.airport-dubai.net/terminal-1.php Are you self-transferring and will you have checked luggage? How long between your scheduled arrival and departure times?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Voting to put on hold.